# Perfect way to use MySQL data updating/storing with no lag and error at updating stats

Tags: mysql, bukkit

I'm having issues loading/storing MySQL data, this is my code

```
public void loadPlayer(Player p) {

if (isPlayerInDataBase(p)) {

    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Connection connection = sql.getConnection();
            try {
                PreparedStatement select = connection
                        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `MurderData` WHERE playername='" + p.getName() + "'");
                ResultSet result = select.executeQuery();

                if (getPlayerData(p) != null) {
                    while (result.next()) {

                        getPlayerData(p).setdeaths(result.getInt("deaths"));
                        getPlayerData(p).setkills(result.getInt("kills"));
                        getPlayerData(p).setwins(result.getInt("wins"));
                        getPlayerData(p).setlose(result.getInt("loses"));
                        getPlayerData(p).setscore(result.getInt("score"));
                        getPlayerData(p).setcoins(result.getInt("coins"));
                    }

                    CloseResultSet(result);

                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
} else {
    Connection connection = sql.getConnection();
    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO `MurderData` (playername, wins, deaths, loses, kills, coins, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                insert.setString(1, p.getName());
                insert.setInt(2, 0);
                insert.setInt(3, 0);
                insert.setInt(4, 0);
                insert.setInt(5, 0);
                insert.setInt(6, 0);
                insert.setInt(7, 0);
                insert.executeUpdate();
                ClosePreparedStatement(insert);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

public boolean isPlayerInDataBase(Player p) {
        Connection connection = sql.getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement select = connection
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `MurderData` WHERE playername='" + p.getName() + "'");
            ResultSet result = select.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                CloseResultSet(result);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So basically the question is, should i close prepared statements after updating MySQL data? and should i make that have a delay like close it after 5 seconds? can i optimize this code to make it better?

The is player in data base is it alright?

this is my 2 closing methods:

```
public void CloseResultSet(ResultSet s) {

        new BukkitRunnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (s != null) {
                    try {
                        s.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }.runTaskLater(this, 20 * getConfig().getInt("close-sql-statements-after"));
    }

    public void ClosePreparedStatement(PreparedStatement s) {

        new BukkitRunnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (s != null) {
                    try {
                        s.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }.runTaskLater(this, 20 * getConfig().getInt("close-sql-statements-after"));

    }
```

Update: this is the second problem, first problem is the small lag spikes second problem is storing data in line 252

```
public void setSQLData(Player p, int kills, int deaths, int loses, int wins, int coins, int score) {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(plugin, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Connection connection = plugin.sql.getConnection();
                try {
                    PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(
                            "INSERT INTO `MurderData` (playername, wins, deaths, loses, kills, coins, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    insert.setString(1, p.getName());
                    insert.setInt(2, wins);
                    insert.setInt(3, deaths);
                    insert.setInt(4, loses);
                    insert.setInt(5, kills);
                    insert.setInt(6, coins);
                    insert.setInt(7, score);
                    insert.executeUpdate();// error line 252
                    plugin.ClosePreparedStatement(insert);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
    }

     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3082)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2968)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3516)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2407)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2325)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at me.joseph.murder.api.MurderAPI$1.run(MurderAPI.java:252)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:53)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2529)
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]:  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
```

Comment: Instead of running it this way, syncronously with Bukkit's main thread, run it in an async thread, making it background. It shouldn't lock your server, thus not causing lag

Comment: Also, running a query in `isPlayerInDataBase(Player p)` and then running the exact same query again if he is in the database seems a bit redundant. Just use the data you got during the check.

Comment: This could be completely off base, but another way (aside from the two mentioned by Kerooker and Solarflare) to help with the lag is (with system resources allowing) to cache recent players that leave, so if they return soon (say relog) you do not have to fetch their data again. Now this would only make things faster if you have the system resources allow it, and if they do not then this could make things slower. Now Caching is a common practice; however, I do not know how true this for mysql or bukkit/minecraft.

Comment: Basically, I'm following this tutorial here, https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/asynchronously-working-with-a-database/, about the second comment, you mean that I need to check once? like saving in config if player is in database?, im currently not having much lag with this current code, but the main problem is that the closing prepared statements and result sets are causing errors like could not save/load data after closing result sets and prepared stats that's why I made that method to close them after 5 seconds but still causing errors (not for me) but for people who use the plugin.

Comment: Update added one more problem, my main problem is storing data also the second problem is small lag spikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

As far as I can see, you are closing the connection every time after you executet a Query/Update. This is unfortunately quite imperformant. It would be better if opened a MySQL connection when the Plugin starts and close it again when the plugin stops.

I personally made it this way:(Doesn't mean you have to do it this way)

The connection variable:

```
private static Connection connection;
```

The connect function:

```
    public static void connect(String host, String user, String password, String database) {
    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), () -> {

        //close Connection if still active
        if (connection != null) {
            close();
        }

        //connect to database host
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + database, user, password);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    });
}
```

My function to update/write entries into the database:

```
    public void Update(final String qry) {
    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), () -> {
        try {
            Statement stnt = connection.createStatement();
            stnt.executeUpdate(qry);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```

My function to query information from the database:

As you can see is this function not asynchronous. I unfortunately didn't managed it by now to get this function asynchronous. But you can easily workaround this by just making the function call asynchronous. ex:

`Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), () -> { Query("your query");
});`

```
    public ResultSet Query(String qry) {
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        Statement stnt = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stnt.executeQuery(qry);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

The close function:

```
    public static void close() {
    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), () -> {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

A disadvantage of this way is that you can only connect to one Database at a Time(which was in my case just fine).

Hope it helps you. I also struggled a lot with weird MySQL Errors. Fortunately with this code everything works just fine.

To answer your question:

```
[22:31:18] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 71/WARN]: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
```

As far as I know this means that the connection to the MySQL Server is closed even though the plugin tries to use it.
As mentioned above opening a connection at the start and leaving it open until the plugin stops should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who helped i've figured out the problem was on this line

```
 public void setSQLData(Player p, int kills, int deaths, int loses, int wins, int coins, int score) {


  Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(plugin, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Connection connection = plugin.sql.getConnection();
            try {
                PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO `MurderData` (playername, wins, deaths, loses, kills, coins, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

it should be UPDATE not insert