# MySQL lag on get (SELECT)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My problem is that there is update troo at the get level so the server starts to lag 70% tps loss I do not know how to optimize its?

```java
public static int getCoins(Player player) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement q = Main.sql.prepareStatement("SELECT Coins FROM Players WHERE Players_UUID = ?");
        q.setString(1, player.getUniqueId().toString());

        int coins= 0;
        ResultSet rs = q.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            balance = rs.getInt("Coins");
        }

        q.close();

        return coins;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: How many entries are in your Coins table?

Comment: Do you have a unique index on Players_UUID column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perfect way to use MySQL data updating/storing with no lag and error at updating stats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405712/perfect-way-to-use-mysql-data-updating-storing-with-no-lag-and-error-at-updating)

Comment: Your question is quite unclear but one of many reason can be that there is no index on Players_UUID

Comment: My problem is that the tps are weak with this method to get the corners in my scoreboard which update its every 1 seconds I know how optimized its more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do a sql query every time to get coins, just create a int or hashmap field with the data and check every X time if data has changed.

if it has changed send update to mysql server and mark that data has saved like two hashmap/int fields.

hashmap1 = database data
hashmap2 = server data

if hashmap1 and hashmap2 are same don't update.

Do the update in async function like schedulerAsync or thread.

Here a similar example:

```
package test;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.entity.Zombie;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class Event extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    // Mysql update data
    public static ConcurrentHashMap<UUID, Integer> player_zombiekills = new ConcurrentHashMap<UUID, Integer>();

    // Mysql connection data
    public static Connection connection;
    private String host = "localhost";
    private String database = "DB";
    private String username = "user";
    private String password = "123";
    private int port = 3306;

    //Kill zombie event
    @EventHandler
    public void zombieDeath(EntityDeathEvent eve) {
        if (!(eve.getEntity() instanceof Zombie)) return; // Stop if death is not zombie
        if (!(eve.getEntity().getKiller() instanceof Player)) return; // Stop if killer is not player
        UUID uid = eve.getEntity().getKiller().getUniqueId(); // Save player uuid
        if (player_zombiekills.contains(uid)) player_zombiekills.put(uid, 0); // Set kills 0 if not exist in hashmap
        player_zombiekills.put(uid, player_zombiekills.get(uid) + 1); // plus 1 kills value
    }

    //On enable connection
    public void onEnable() {
        try {
            if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) return;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
            if (!connection.isClosed()) System.out.println("[MySQL] " + "Connected to '" + database + "'");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("[MySQL] " + e.getMessage());
        }

        new BukkitRunnable() {
            public void run() {
                // for updates
                for (Entry<UUID, Integer> ent : player_zombiekills.entrySet()) {
                    try {
                        // send update
                        connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("UPDATE `tablename` SET `zombiekills`=`zombiekills`+" + ent.getValue() + " WHERE `uuid`='" + ent.getKey().toString() + "'");
                        // Sucess remove entry from hashmap to reset kills
                        player_zombiekills.remove(ent.getKey());
                    } catch (SQLException e) { // If error
                        System.err.println("[MySQL] " + e.getMessage()); // Print error in console
                    }
                }
            }
        }.runTaskTimerAsynchronously(this, 20, 20 * 60 * 10); // Run async loop every 10 minutes
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I do not see how to do because if you change the data in BDD it does not change on the server so if I do not get every 1 second its will not work so I have optimized with an async but how without return To get the coins...

Comment: on PlayerJoinEvent add player to list like "pending_get_list" and in next async task do mysql select and save data in any field.

And if modify add to another list like "pending_sync_list" and in next async task do mysql update.

Comment: Possible give example ?